# Porting J2EE application from weblogic to Jboss, JTS? (weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, java-transaction-service

My weblogic(8.1) application uses weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver to connect to Oracle.

I'd like to port this app to JBOSS(4.0) and quick googling did not yield the correct driver to replace this JDBC JTS driver with in order to connect from Jboss, ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use WebLogic's wrapper driver in a non-WebLogic application server?

As it is written [here](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jdbc/rmidriver.html#1026194), I presume you needed it in WebLogic in order for the Oracle driver to participate in XA (two-phase commit) transactions, if that's so I would suggest that you use the native [XA DataSource that oracle provides](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/j2ee/jdbc/JDBC_in_J2EE.html) (oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource) and fetch the datasource from the JNDI, along with JBoss's own [transaction manager](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/transaction.html).

Here is one [sample](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/ch10s16.html) and a more [elaborate one](http://wiki.osuosl.org/display/ERA/Indiana+-+Setting+Up+JBoss+Datasources), of the datasource configuration. And the link to the JBoss transaction manager [documentation](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/Transactions_JTA_Programmers_Guide/).

Comment: Thanks, exactly, I am trying to get rid of that weblogic reference, your answer should do it.